# write regex code in java for following data

Tags: java, regex

```
    <table> 
<tr> 
<td style="width:180px"> 
<a href="/search?q=user:240698+[java]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'java'">java</a><span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;176</span><br> 
<a href="/search?q=user:240698+[servlets]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'servlets'">servlets</a><span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;25</span><br> 
<a href="/search?q=user:240698+[jsp]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'jsp'">jsp</a><span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;11</span><br> 
<a href="/search?q=user:240698+[core]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'core'">core</a><span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;9</span><br> 
</tr>
</table>
```

from the above code I need to fetch only java, servlets, jsp and core.

Can anybody plz help me out to write a regex in java to fetch those?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) use regex to parse HTML, use [HTML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+html+parser) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I'd have to use Regex, I'd try

```
"/search\?q=user:\d+\+\[(\w*)\]"
```